# What is the right operator in vb.net for test if a String is not equal?

Tags: string, vb.net, inequality

I tried something like this

```
Do Until !test.equals("1234") Or !test.equals("xyxyxyx")  
... 
Loop
```

How can I write that in vb.net?

Comment: `<>` is the VB.NET value inequality operator, which you could find out easily enough, so if you used that and didn't get the expected result then you did it wrong. Maybe show that and explain what you want to happen rather than expecting us to work it out from code that doesn't do it.

Comment: Try using `Not` instead of !. `Do Until Not 1 = 2`

Comment: @dieMstar - the loop will never run because test can't be equal to two different values.

Answer (score 4):

The ! in other language is Not is vb.net

```
Do Until Not test.equals("1234") Or Not test.equals("xyxyxyx")
```

Comment: For those not fully aware of the way the VB rewrites string comparisons when the comparison operators ( `=, <>, >, <, >=, <=, etc.`) are used, this syntax is the safest bet to get the results you expect.  The `Equals` method of the string class will never yield different results because of compiler options or per code file directives.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference///operators/comparison-operators

```
Do Until test <> 1234 Or test <> "xyxyxyx"
... 
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

`Do While test <> "1234" or test <> "xyxyxyx"
   //your code here...
Loop`

**From Microsoft Documentation**

[Do Loop Statement(visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/do-loop-statement)

[Comparison operators in Visual Basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/operators-and-expressions/comparison-operators)